# How do I intialize a Search tree pointer for SACSegmentation?

Tags: point-cloud-library, pcl

From PCL I am using **SACSegmentation** function in order to find a specific shape from a Point Cloud. One of the options I wish to use is called `setSamplesMaxDist(A,B)`.
`A` is the radius (double variable) while `B` is set with `SearchPtr`.

I am not sure how to initialize `SearchPtr`.

I have already tried setting `pcl::search::Search<PointT>::Ptr B`, the Build of which crashed during start up.
When I tried `pcl::search::Search<PointT>::Ptr B(new search::Search<PointT>)`, Visual Studio would not allow me.

So what is the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

`pcl::search::Search` is the interface that all search classes inherit from.

You need to use one of the [concrete implementations](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/group__search.html).

Example using **KdTree**:

```
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>);
tree->setInputCloud(cloud);

pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal> seg;
seg.setSamplesMaxDist(radius, tree);
```